# Saving Data using Ajax and Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I just have an input form that I want to save to my database using Ajax, PHP and Laravel this code works fine to my other modules. But I can't just find the error why this code not working fine. Help me to spot what's wrong with my code. The Route is correct, my controller seems correct too but I really doubt my ajax if it's correct.

HTML:

```
  <input id="schedDate" name = "schedDate" type="text" class="datetimepicker-input form__field" placeholder="Schedule Date" data-target="#schedDate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">

  <input id="timeIn" name = "timeIn" type="text" class="datetimepicker-input form__field" placeholder="Time In" data-target="#timeIn" data-toggle="datetimepicker">

  <input id="timeOut" name = "timeOut" type="text" class="datetimepicker-input form__field" placeholder="Time Out" data-target="#timeOut" data-toggle="datetimepicker">

   <select id="cmbShift" name = "cmbShift" class="form__field" placeholder="Shift Type">
       <option value="">- Select Shift -</option>
       <option value="Pre-Shift">Pre-Shift</option>
       <option value="Post-Shift">Post-Shift</option>
   </select>

    <textarea type="text" id="txtReason" name = "txtReason" class="form__field" placeholder="Reason"></textarea>
    <input id="btnApplyAlter" name="btnApplyAlter" class="btnApplyAlter btn btn-sm button blue pull-right" type="button" value="Apply Overtime" style="width:220px;"/>
```

Here's my Ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnApplyAlter", function(){

var c = confirm("Apply this Overtime?");
var schedDate = $("#schedDate").val();
var timeIn = $("#timeIn").val();
var timeOut = $("#timeOut").val();
var cmbShift = $("#cmbShift").val();
var txtReason = $("#txtReason").val();

if(c == true)
{
    $.ajax({
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: "{{ route('saveovertime') }}",
        method: "POST",
        data: {sched_date:schedDate,time_in:timeIn,time_out:timeOut,cmbShift:cmbShift,txtReason:txtReason}, 
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            refresh_Table();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
}
 });
```

Here's my Controller:

```
    public function save_overtime(Request $request){
    //Code for getting the current date of Asia/Manila
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $today = strtotime($todays_date);
    $todayDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $today); 
    //Code for getting the current date of Asia/Manila

    $apply_overtime = new OvertimeRecords;
    $apply_overtime->company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
    $apply_overtime->date_applied = $todayDate;
    $apply_overtime->sched_date = $request->sched_date;
    $apply_overtime->shift_applied = $request->cmbShift;
    $apply_overtime->date_timein = $request->time_in;
    $apply_overtime->date_timeout = $request->time_out;
    $apply_overtime->reason = $request->txtReason;
    $apply_overtime->lu_by = auth()->user()->name; 
    $apply_overtime->save();
    $message = "Overtime Applied Succesfully!"; 
    echo json_encode($message);
}
```

and here's my route:

```
 Route::post('overtimerecords/saveovertime', 'UsersController\\OvertimeRecordsController@save_overtime')->name('saveovertime');
```

Error:
[image]

and this error highlighted straight to ajax

[image]

Comment: Any errors are shown?

Comment: which error you got? Validation? or example.com/saveovertime?token=231312123

Comment: show us the route added as well as the html form

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Maybe instead of `echo json_encode($message);` try return 'return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => $message]);` and put try catch block to find problem

Comment: Open network. Click XHR and post it again. Let us know that error please.

Comment: 500, something is happening wrong on server side, the ajax call, checkout webserver logs, you will get the error.

Comment: Error too using that code.. MethodAllowedExeption (No Message)

Comment: You have \\ in your post url  remove \ from route post url

Comment: @ViperTecPro what "\\" ? You  mean the UsersController\\OvertimeRecordsController?

Comment: Problem occurs when you submit it via ajax before or after that ?

Comment: Yes i mean that

Comment: That line used to detect which folder and controller that route is looking for.. I tried to remove but still getting the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192347/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-king-rg).

Answer (score 0):

Put jquery first, then other js in header. Its due to jquery seems to appear after bootstrap js.